# Не передаются данные методом POST

Tags: php, post, get

Данные которые были отправлены методом POST не передаются скрипту. Через метод GET всё работает. Пример кода.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="value">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php


ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset ($_POST['value'])) {
        $n = $_POST['value'];

        function factorial($n)
        {

            if ($n <= 1 || $n == 1) {
                return 1;
            } else {

                return $n * factorial($n - 1);

            }
        }

        echo factorial($n) . "<br>";


        function factLoop($n)
        {
            $result = 1;
            for ($i = 2; $i <= $n; $i++) {
                $result = $result * $i;
            }
            return $result;
        }

        echo factLoop($n);

    } else {
        echo "Введіть число";
    }
}
print_r($_POST) ;
```

Comment: Как вы поняли что не работает? Вполне себе работает. Что говорит `Network` в инструментах разработчика? ... Кстати, чтоб надпись выводилась введите число надо проверять значение на пустоту `if (isset ($_POST['value']) && !empty($_POST['value']))` .... ведь если пост отправился, то значение существует (если конечно на форме было поле с таким именем)

Comment: value:10
submit:Submit

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:63342/sonicTrain/www/index.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:63342

Comment: `value:10 submit:Submit` нуу.. данные передаются....

Comment: Да данные передаются, но print_r выводит пустой массив, и функции не срабатывают.

Comment: Может проблема в настройка сервера? Использую ХAMPP, в настройках ничего не менял.

Comment: Через метод GET все работает.

Comment: У `XAMPP`, возможно. судя по http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827218/post-is-empty-on-xampp-when-post-from-remote-form#comment26026129_17827455

Comment: У меня всё работает (XAMPP, Linux). Но я сомневаюсь, что дело в XAMPP; вы что-то не досмотрели.

Comment: Посмотрите что скажет вам print_r($_REQUEST)

Comment: Вся проблема была в PHPStorm. Если запустить скрипт из IDE то она использует свой сервер, а он не передает данные методом POST.

Answer (score 1):

Вся проблема была в PHPStorm. Если запустить скрипт из IDE то она использует свой сервер, а он не передает данные методом POST